# Plugin directory says that my plugin it's not availabe in Spanish, but it is

Tags: plugin-development, language, plugin-repository

I uploaded my first plugin to the wordpress repository, it includes the .po and .mo files for Spanish in the languages folder; the Text Domain and Domain Path strings are also specified in the plugin header, and the plugin works fine both in english and spanish when installed. However, when I go to the spanish version of the wordpress plugin directory (at https://es.wordpress.org/plugins), it says that the plugin it's still not available in Spanish.

I tried uploading the po using the web interface in translate.wordpress.org, but now the translations are in "waiting" state and I'm not sure how to approve them

Maybe I'm missing something, should I add something to the plugin? I can't find enough documentation about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to approve your own plugin translations you have to post in the Polyglots site:

https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/

a message like this:

"Hello, I’m the author of the {insert plugin name and a link} plugin. Could you allow me to approve translations in my native language (es_ES), please?"

And select "Editor Request" in the "Post Type" dropdown. Hopefully an editor of the Spanish team will grant you Editor privileges for your translation and you will be able to approve it.

Here you can see an example post:

https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/2018/08/13/pte-request-for-secure-admin-ip/